# JWT авторизация в PHP Ошибка Uncaught Error: Class 'JWT' not found

Tags: php, jwt

Есть класс JWT.php

```
<?php

namespace Firebase\JWT;

use \DomainException;
use \InvalidArgumentException;
use \UnexpectedValueException;
use \DateTime;

/**
 * JSON Web Token implementation, based on this spec:
 * https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519
 *
 * PHP version 5
 *
 * @category Authentication
 * @package  Authentication_JWT
 * @author   Neuman Vong <neuman@twilio.com>
 * @author   Anant Narayanan <anant@php.net>
 * @license  http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause 3-clause BSD
 * @link     https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt
 */

class JWT
{

    const ASN1_INTEGER = 0x02;
    const ASN1_SEQUENCE = 0x10;
    const ASN1_BIT_STRING = 0x03;

    /**
     * When checking nbf, iat or expiration times,
     * we want to provide some extra leeway time to
     * account for clock skew.
     */
    public static $leeway = 0;

    /**
     * Allow the current timestamp to be specified.
     * Useful for fixing a value within unit testing.
     *
     * Will default to PHP time() value if null.
     */
    public static $timestamp = null;

    public static $supported_algs = array(
        'ES256' => array('openssl', 'SHA256'),
        'HS256' => array('hash_hmac', 'SHA256'),
        'HS384' => array('hash_hmac', 'SHA384'),
        'HS512' => array('hash_hmac', 'SHA512'),
        'RS256' => array('openssl', 'SHA256'),
        'RS384' => array('openssl', 'SHA384'),
        'RS512' => array('openssl', 'SHA512'),
    );

    /**
     * Decodes a JWT string into a PHP object.
     *
     * @param string                    $jwt            The JWT
     * @param string|array|resource     $key            The key, or map of keys.
     *                                                  If the algorithm used is asymmetric, this is the public key
     * @param array                     $allowed_algs   List of supported verification algorithms
     *                                                  Supported algorithms are 'ES256', 'HS256', 'HS384', 'HS512', 'RS256', 'RS384', and 'RS512'
     *
     * @return object The JWT's payload as a PHP object
     *
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException     Provided JWT was invalid
     * @throws SignatureInvalidException    Provided JWT was invalid because the signature verification failed
     * @throws BeforeValidException         Provided JWT is trying to be used before it's eligible as defined by 'nbf'
     * @throws BeforeValidException         Provided JWT is trying to be used before it's been created as defined by 'iat'
     * @throws ExpiredException             Provided JWT has since expired, as defined by the 'exp' claim
     *
     * @uses jsonDecode
     * @uses urlsafeB64Decode
     */
    public static function decode($jwt, $key, array $allowed_algs = array())
    {
        $timestamp = \is_null(static::$timestamp) ? \time() : static::$timestamp;

        if (empty($key)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Key may not be empty');
        }
        $tks = \explode('.', $jwt);
        if (\count($tks) != 3) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Wrong number of segments');
        }
        list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = $tks;
        if (null === ($header = static::jsonDecode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($headb64)))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid header encoding');
        }
        if (null === $payload = static::jsonDecode(static::urlsafeB64Decode($bodyb64))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid claims encoding');
        }
        if (false === ($sig = static::urlsafeB64Decode($cryptob64))) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Invalid signature encoding');
        }
        if (empty($header->alg)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Empty algorithm');
        }
        if (empty(static::$supported_algs[$header->alg])) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Algorithm not supported');
        }
        if (!\in_array($header->alg, $allowed_algs)) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Algorithm not allowed');
        }
        if ($header->alg === 'ES256') {
            // OpenSSL expects an ASN.1 DER sequence for ES256 signatures
            $sig = self::signatureToDER($sig);
        }

        if (\is_array($key) || $key instanceof \ArrayAccess) {
            if (isset($header->kid)) {
                if (!isset($key[$header->kid])) {
                    throw new UnexpectedValueException('"kid" invalid, unable to lookup correct key');
                }
                $key = $key[$header->kid];
            } else {
                throw new UnexpectedValueException('"kid" empty, unable to lookup correct key');
            }
        }

        // Check the signature
        if (!static::verify("$headb64.$bodyb64", $sig, $key, $header->alg)) {
            throw new SignatureInvalidException('Signature verification failed');
        }

        // Check the nbf if it is defined. This is the time that the
        // token can actually be used. If it's not yet that time, abort.
        if (isset($payload->nbf) && $payload->nbf > ($timestamp + static::$leeway)) {
            throw new BeforeValidException(
                'Cannot handle token prior to ' . \date(DateTime::ISO8601, $payload->nbf)
            );
        }

        // Check that this token has been created before 'now'. This prevents
        // using tokens that have been created for later use (and haven't
        // correctly used the nbf claim).
        if (isset($payload->iat) && $payload->iat > ($timestamp + static::$leeway)) {
            throw new BeforeValidException(
                'Cannot handle token prior to ' . \date(DateTime::ISO8601, $payload->iat)
            );
        }

        // Check if this token has expired.
        if (isset($payload->exp) && ($timestamp - static::$leeway) >= $payload->exp) {
            throw new ExpiredException('Expired token');
        }

        return $payload;
    }

    /**
     * Converts and signs a PHP object or array into a JWT string.
     *
     * @param object|array  $payload    PHP object or array
     * @param string        $key        The secret key.
     *                                  If the algorithm used is asymmetric, this is the private key
     * @param string        $alg        The signing algorithm.
     *                                  Supported algorithms are 'ES256', 'HS256', 'HS384', 'HS512', 'RS256', 'RS384', and 'RS512'
     * @param mixed         $keyId
     * @param array         $head       An array with header elements to attach
     *
     * @return string A signed JWT
     *
     * @uses jsonEncode
     * @uses urlsafeB64Encode
     */
    public static function encode($payload, $key, $alg = 'HS256', $keyId = null, $head = null)
    {
        $header = array('typ' => 'JWT', 'alg' => $alg);
        if ($keyId !== null) {
            $header['kid'] = $keyId;
        }
        if (isset($head) && \is_array($head)) {
            $header = \array_merge($head, $header);
        }
        $segments = array();
        $segments[] = static::urlsafeB64Encode(static::jsonEncode($header));
        $segments[] = static::urlsafeB64Encode(static::jsonEncode($payload));
        $signing_input = \implode('.', $segments);

        $signature = static::sign($signing_input, $key, $alg);
        $segments[] = static::urlsafeB64Encode($signature);

        return \implode('.', $segments);
    }

    /**
     * Sign a string with a given key and algorithm.
     *
     * @param string            $msg    The message to sign
     * @param string|resource   $key    The secret key
     * @param string            $alg    The signing algorithm.
     *                                  Supported algorithms are 'ES256', 'HS256', 'HS384', 'HS512', 'RS256', 'RS384', and 'RS512'
     *
     * @return string An encrypted message
     *
     * @throws DomainException Unsupported algorithm was specified
     */
    public static function sign($msg, $key, $alg = 'HS256')
    {
        if (empty(static::$supported_algs[$alg])) {
            throw new DomainException('Algorithm not supported');
        }
        list($function, $algorithm) = static::$supported_algs[$alg];
        switch ($function) {
            case 'hash_hmac':
                return \hash_hmac($algorithm, $msg, $key, true);
            case 'openssl':
                $signature = '';
                $success = \openssl_sign($msg, $signature, $key, $algorithm);
                if (!$success) {
                    throw new DomainException("OpenSSL unable to sign data");
                } else {
                    if ($alg === 'ES256') {
                        $signature = self::signatureFromDER($signature, 256);
                    }
                    return $signature;
                }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify a signature with the message, key and method. Not all methods
     * are symmetric, so we must have a separate verify and sign method.
     *
     * @param string            $msg        The original message (header and body)
     * @param string            $signature  The original signature
     * @param string|resource   $key        For HS*, a string key works. for RS*, must be a resource of an openssl public key
     * @param string            $alg        The algorithm
     *
     * @return bool
     *
     * @throws DomainException Invalid Algorithm or OpenSSL failure
     */
    private static function verify($msg, $signature, $key, $alg)
    {
        if (empty(static::$supported_algs[$alg])) {
            throw new DomainException('Algorithm not supported');
        }

        list($function, $algorithm) = static::$supported_algs[$alg];
        switch ($function) {
            case 'openssl':
                $success = \openssl_verify($msg, $signature, $key, $algorithm);
                if ($success === 1) {
                    return true;
                } elseif ($success === 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                // returns 1 on success, 0 on failure, -1 on error.
                throw new DomainException(
                    'OpenSSL error: ' . \openssl_error_string()
                );
            case 'hash_hmac':
            default:
                $hash = \hash_hmac($algorithm, $msg, $key, true);
                if (\function_exists('hash_equals')) {
                    return \hash_equals($signature, $hash);
                }
                $len = \min(static::safeStrlen($signature), static::safeStrlen($hash));

                $status = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
                    $status |= (\ord($signature[$i]) ^ \ord($hash[$i]));
                }
                $status |= (static::safeStrlen($signature) ^ static::safeStrlen($hash));

                return ($status === 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decode a JSON string into a PHP object.
     *
     * @param string $input JSON string
     *
     * @return object Object representation of JSON string
     *
     * @throws DomainException Provided string was invalid JSON
     */
    public static function jsonDecode($input)
    {
        if (\version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>=') && !(\defined('JSON_C_VERSION') && PHP_INT_SIZE > 4)) {
            /** In PHP >=5.4.0, json_decode() accepts an options parameter, that allows you
             * to specify that large ints (like Steam Transaction IDs) should be treated as
             * strings, rather than the PHP default behaviour of converting them to floats.
             */
            $obj = \json_decode($input, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING);
        } else {
            /** Not all servers will support that, however, so for older versions we must
             * manually detect large ints in the JSON string and quote them (thus converting
             *them to strings) before decoding, hence the preg_replace() call.
             */
            $max_int_length = \strlen((string) PHP_INT_MAX) - 1;
            $json_without_bigints = \preg_replace('/:\s*(-?\d{'.$max_int_length.',})/', ': "$1"', $input);
            $obj = \json_decode($json_without_bigints);
        }

        if ($errno = \json_last_error()) {
            static::handleJsonError($errno);
        } elseif ($obj === null && $input !== 'null') {
            throw new DomainException('Null result with non-null input');
        }
        return $obj;
    }

    /**
     * Encode a PHP object into a JSON string.
     *
     * @param object|array $input A PHP object or array
     *
     * @return string JSON representation of the PHP object or array
     *
     * @throws DomainException Provided object could not be encoded to valid JSON
     */
    public static function jsonEncode($input)
    {
        $json = \json_encode($input);
        if ($errno = \json_last_error()) {
            static::handleJsonError($errno);
        } elseif ($json === 'null' && $input !== null) {
            throw new DomainException('Null result with non-null input');
        }
        return $json;
    }

    /**
     * Decode a string with URL-safe Base64.
     *
     * @param string $input A Base64 encoded string
     *
     * @return string A decoded string
     */
    public static function urlsafeB64Decode($input)
    {
        $remainder = \strlen($input) % 4;
        if ($remainder) {
            $padlen = 4 - $remainder;
            $input .= \str_repeat('=', $padlen);
        }
        return \base64_decode(\strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }

    /**
     * Encode a string with URL-safe Base64.
     *
     * @param string $input The string you want encoded
     *
     * @return string The base64 encode of what you passed in
     */
    public static function urlsafeB64Encode($input)
    {
        return \str_replace('=', '', \strtr(\base64_encode($input), '+/', '-_'));
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to create a JSON error.
     *
     * @param int $errno An error number from json_last_error()
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private static function handleJsonError($errno)
    {
        $messages = array(
            JSON_ERROR_DEPTH => 'Maximum stack depth exceeded',
            JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH => 'Invalid or malformed JSON',
            JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR => 'Unexpected control character found',
            JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX => 'Syntax error, malformed JSON',
            JSON_ERROR_UTF8 => 'Malformed UTF-8 characters' //PHP >= 5.3.3
        );
        throw new DomainException(
            isset($messages[$errno])
            ? $messages[$errno]
            : 'Unknown JSON error: ' . $errno
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of bytes in cryptographic strings.
     *
     * @param string $str
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private static function safeStrlen($str)
    {
        if (\function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
            return \mb_strlen($str, '8bit');
        }
        return \strlen($str);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an ECDSA signature to an ASN.1 DER sequence
     *
     * @param   string $sig The ECDSA signature to convert
     * @return  string The encoded DER object
     */
    private static function signatureToDER($sig)
    {
        // Separate the signature into r-value and s-value
        list($r, $s) = \str_split($sig, (int) (\strlen($sig) / 2));

        // Trim leading zeros
        $r = \ltrim($r, "\x00");
        $s = \ltrim($s, "\x00");

        // Convert r-value and s-value from unsigned big-endian integers to
        // signed two's complement
        if (\ord($r[0]) > 0x7f) {
            $r = "\x00" . $r;
        }
        if (\ord($s[0]) > 0x7f) {
            $s = "\x00" . $s;
        }

        return self::encodeDER(
            self::ASN1_SEQUENCE,
            self::encodeDER(self::ASN1_INTEGER, $r) .
            self::encodeDER(self::ASN1_INTEGER, $s)
        );
    }

    /**
     * Encodes a value into a DER object.
     *
     * @param   int     $type DER tag
     * @param   string  $value the value to encode
     * @return  string  the encoded object
     */
    private static function encodeDER($type, $value)
    {
        $tag_header = 0;
        if ($type === self::ASN1_SEQUENCE) {
            $tag_header |= 0x20;
        }

        // Type
        $der = \chr($tag_header | $type);

        // Length
        $der .= \chr(\strlen($value));

        return $der . $value;
    }

    /**
     * Encodes signature from a DER object.
     *
     * @param   string  $der binary signature in DER format
     * @param   int     $keySize the number of bits in the key
     * @return  string  the signature
     */
    private static function signatureFromDER($der, $keySize)
    {
        // OpenSSL returns the ECDSA signatures as a binary ASN.1 DER SEQUENCE
        list($offset, $_) = self::readDER($der);
        list($offset, $r) = self::readDER($der, $offset);
        list($offset, $s) = self::readDER($der, $offset);

        // Convert r-value and s-value from signed two's compliment to unsigned
        // big-endian integers
        $r = \ltrim($r, "\x00");
        $s = \ltrim($s, "\x00");

        // Pad out r and s so that they are $keySize bits long
        $r = \str_pad($r, $keySize / 8, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $s = \str_pad($s, $keySize / 8, "\x00", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        return $r . $s;
    }

    /**
     * Reads binary DER-encoded data and decodes into a single object
     *
     * @param string $der the binary data in DER format
     * @param int $offset the offset of the data stream containing the object
     * to decode
     * @return array [$offset, $data] the new offset and the decoded object
     */
    private static function readDER($der, $offset = 0)
    {
        $pos = $offset;
        $size = \strlen($der);
        $constructed = (\ord($der[$pos]) >> 5) & 0x01;
        $type = \ord($der[$pos++]) & 0x1f;

        // Length
        $len = \ord($der[$pos++]);
        if ($len & 0x80) {
            $n = $len & 0x1f;
            $len = 0;
            while ($n-- && $pos < $size) {
                $len = ($len << 8) | \ord($der[$pos++]);
            }
        }

        // Value
        if ($type == self::ASN1_BIT_STRING) {
            $pos++; // Skip the first contents octet (padding indicator)
            $data = \substr($der, $pos, $len - 1);
            $pos += $len - 1;
        } elseif (!$constructed) {
            $data = \substr($der, $pos, $len);
            $pos += $len;
        } else {
            $data = null;
        }

        return array($pos, $data);
    }
}
```

подключаю в своём файле через пространства имён

```
<?php
   // Include php JWT implementation library
   // https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/tree/master/src

    namespace lib\sso;
    use     JWT;
    use     BeforeValidException;
    use     ExpiredException;
    use     SignatureInvalidException;
      /* require_once ("./lib/sso/JWT.php");
       require_once ("./lib/sso/BeforeValidException.php");
       require_once ("./lib/sso/ExpiredException.php");
       require_once ("./lib/sso/SignatureInvalidException.php");*/

       const PROTOCOL_STRING       = 'https://';
       const ISPRING_LEARN_DOMAIN  = '***.ispringlearn.com';
       const ISPRING_JWT_LOGIN_URL = '/sso/login/jwt?jwt=';

       const EXAMPLE_USER_EMAIL                    = 'user@mail.com';
       const EXAMPLE_USER_PASSWORD_ON_YOUR_SERVER  = 'verySecurePassword';

       // Enter the same secret key here: %Your_iSpring_Learn_domain%/settings/sso/jwt
       const EXAMPLE_JWT_SECRET_KEY = '********';
       const EXAMPLE_JWT_ENCODE_ALG = 'HS256';

    $obj = new JWT();
    var_dump($obj);
```

На var_dump получаю

> Uncaught Error: Class 'JWT' not found

Все пути проверил все верно, если прямо в файле класса  JWT.php получить обект , все получается. Из другого файла нет. Почему???

Comment: Потому что имя класса `\Firebase\JWT\JWT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `use Firebase\JWT\JWT;` вместо `use JWT;` посколько пространство имён второго файла не совпадает с пространством имён класса `JWT`;

Answer (score 0):

Как написал **@user9519595** - у Вас неправильные `namespace`.
Вы можете использовать профессиональную IDE, к примеру `PhpStorm`, либо `intellij idea` от `JetBrains`. Они пожалуй самые удобные и помогут Вам избежать подобных ошибок в будущем.
Но написал я это не чтобы подтвердить то, что действительно проблема в пространстве имен, а чтобы уберечь Вас от `JWT`. Если у вас не `API` сервер на `PHP` с фронтендом к примеру на `Vue` / `React`, то лучше всего использовать сессии, токен очень легко подделать, либо перехватить, по этому нужно выдавать постоянный токен лишь для работы с временным. Ко всему этому `Firebase JWT` не самое лучше и удобное решение, очень малый функционал и возможности. Лучше всего смотрите в сторону **`jwt-framework`**, либо же **`spomky-labs/jose`**. Конечно, если Вы лишь учитесь, то для саморазвития подойдет любой генератор `JWT`, но лучше сразу начинать с "хорошего" и "безопасного" :)